# Optimizing a stored procedure that uses cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

There is a long running stored procedure. The 2nd table (visit) is used just for the results to be used in the where clause while retrieving records form the first table (approvals).

Below is the DDL of the two tables involved, and the script of the stored procedure. Apparently, as it is just a sample, it doesn't display no records; thus, there are not bottlenecks observed with this sample data. But imagine, having many userr_ids in the cursor. 
There is also additional cost as it is calling another stored procedure. Is there any way I can optimize the query?

DDL of the tables

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Approvals](
    userr_id [int] NOT NULL,
    appro_id [int] NOT NULL,
    app_units [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    c_units [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    usedunits [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    deleted [bit] NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO approvals 
VALUES
(4262,  29, 36.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(1717,  30, 24.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(4743,  31, 76.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(4460,  33, 36.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(4488,  35, 36.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(3871,  36, 24.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(3561,  37, 12.00,  1,  3.00,   0),
(4828,  38, 36.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(3828,  39, 24.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(4101,  40, 24.00,  1,  0.00,   0)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visit](
    userr_id [int] NULL,
    appro_id [int] NULL,
    c_secondary [bit] NULL,
    auth_exceeded [bit] NOT NULL,
    tperiod [int] NOT NULL,
    contratrate [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO visit 
VALUES
(5329,  NULL,   0, 0,   419,    0.00),
(4262,  NULL,   0, 0,   419,    0.00),
(5244,  NULL,   0, 0, 419,  0.00),
(4205,  NULL,   0, 0,   419,    0.00),
(4828,  NULL,   0, 0,   419,    0.00),
(5531,  NULL,   0,0,    419,    0.00),
(5558,  NULL,   0,  0, 419, 0.00),
(4460,  NULL,   0,  0, 419, 0.00),
(5547,  NULL,   0,  0, 419, 0.00),
(5219,  NULL,   0,  0, 419, 0.00)
```

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_procedure] 
AS 

DECLARE @userr_id Int, @cnt Int
SET @cnt = 0

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR


    SELECT DISTINCT userr_id 
      FROM (SELECT userr_id, app_units, c_units, usedunits,
                   (SELECT count(*) FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id and auth_exceeded = 0) AS count_notexceeded,
                   (SELECT count(*) FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id ) AS count_all,
                   (SELECT SUM(tperiod) / 60.00 FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id ) AS th_all,
                   (SELECT SUM(tperiod) / 60.00 FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id and auth_exceeded = 0) AS th_notexceeded,
                   (SELECT SUM(contratrate) FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id and auth_exceeded = 0) AS tr_notexceeded,
                   (SELECT SUM(contratrate) FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id ) AS tr_all
              FROM Approvals where deleted = 0) t
     WHERE ((c_units = 0 and (count_all <> usedunits or count_notexceeded > app_units))
        OR  (c_units = 2 and (th_all <> usedunits or th_notexceeded > app_units))
        OR  (c_units = 3 and (tr_all <> usedunits or tr_notexceeded > app_units)))

 OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @userr_id
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
  SET @cnt = @cnt + 1

  EXEC [_name_of_another_stored_procedure] @userr_id

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @userr_id
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Thanks. Any guide is much appreicated.

Comment: Why does it take a long time to run?  Is it opening the cursor?  Is it running the other stored procedure?  In either case what is the query plan and wait stats?

Comment: Basically, it is opening the cursor. I've tried that separately. I think, because it is selecting from the visit table many times in order to process it to use in the where clause.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing the cursor query with something like this, which hopefully won't have to scan multiple times:

```
with t as
(
    SELECT userr_id, app_units, c_units, usedunits,
        sum (case when auth_exceeded = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS count_notexceeded,
        count(*) AS count_all,
        SUM(tperiod) / 60.00 AS th_all,
        SUM(case when auth_exceeded = 0 then tperiod else 0 end) / 60.00 AS th_notexceeded,
        SUM(case when auth_exceeded = 0 then contratrate else 0 end) AS tr_notexceeded,
        SUM(contratrate) AS tr_all
    FROM Approvals 
    JOIN Visit  
      on Visit.appro_id = Approvals.appro_id
    where deleted = 0
    and Visit.c_secondary = 0
    group by userr_id, app_units, c_units, usedunits

)
SELECT DISTINCT userr_id 
FROM t
WHERE ((c_units = 0 and (count_all <> usedunits or count_notexceeded > app_units))
OR  (c_units = 2 and (th_all <> usedunits or th_notexceeded > app_units))
OR  (c_units = 3 and (tr_all <> usedunits or tr_notexceeded > app_units)))
```